# Unknown class: googleMap and 2 more

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, eclipse-adt

My goal is to make Google Maps the Main Activity by following instructions [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/678431/Example-of-using-google-maps-service-and-gps-in-an).

I pasted the code from the site(MainActivity.java's code below) and imported all the required packages(alt+enter). Nevertheless, a few errors remained(Right now, I am focused on one, might ask more about the others in the near future).

The line `if (googleMap == null) {` gets a red line and says 3 things:

`Unknown class googleMap` (This error is only on this *particular* line)

`Unexpected token` (when mouse over `null`) &

`Unexpected token` (when mouse over `if`)

I am using android studio if that helps. Thanks and the code is below-

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    public GoogleMap googleMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

    if (googleMap == null) {

        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync(this);

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Could not create Maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            // Changing map type
            //TODO
        }
    }

    public GpsLocation(Context mContext, TextView gpsStatusTextView) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.gpsStatusTextView = gpsStatusTextView;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                // First get location from Network Provider
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    gpsLocation = new GpsLocation(this, gpsStatusTextView);

    if (gpsLocation.canGetLocation()){
        double longitude = gpsLocation.getLongitude();
        double latitude = gpsLocation.getLatitude();
    }
}
```

Sorry if this is a total **n00b** question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For in-depth information:

Follow these documentations by Google: [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start), [Project Configuration](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/config), [Get API Key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup).

## Getting Started

> This guide is a quick start to adding a map to an Android app. Android Studio is the recommended development environment for building an app with the Google Maps Android API.
>
> 1. Download Android Studio
> 2. Install the Google Play services SDK
> 3. Create a Google Maps project
> 4. Get a Google Maps API key
> 5. Hello Map! Take a look at the code
> 6. Connect an Android device
> 7. Build and run your app

## Project Configuration

In this document describes all the configuration you need in your development project when using the Google Maps Android API in your Android app.

> The overall process of adding a map to an Android application is as follows:
>
> - Install the Android SDK.
> - Install and configure the Google Play services SDK, which includes the Google Maps Android API. *Note*: If you use the Google Maps Android API with a Google Maps APIs Premium Plan license, you must download and configure the Premium Plan SDK instead.
> - Get an API key. To do this, you will need to register a project in the Google Developers Console, find the signing certificate for your app, and create an API key.
> - Add the required settings to your application's manifest.

## Get API Key

> To use the Google Maps Android API, you must register your app project on the Google Developers Console and get a Google API key which you can add to your app. *Note*: There are various types of API keys. You need an *Android key* not a browser key.
>
> Your API key is based on a short form of your app's digital certificate. All Android apps are signed with a digital certificate for which you hold the private key. (Refer to the Android guide to signing your applications for more information about digital certificates.)

Follow these steps and you will get a maps in Main Activity working.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi! I have an API key up and working, and also, what is mapsactivity all about?

Comment: aahhh, i think you misunderstood me! I am still getting that error, but my API key is working, I am pretty sure bout that

Comment: It think I should edit and elaborate my question..It's that _particular_ line in which I am getting unknown class googleMaps. It doesn't show me any error on the next line(which also has that word)!! Maybe something to do with null? You might not understand what I am saying so if you have the time please paste this into some IDE and watch the erros pop up!

Answer (score 0):

add the google map dependency in gradle file and sync your project

Comment: how do we do that?

Comment: google map dependency 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2' was already there in build.gradle